# Where did Dark and Krad come from?

Tags: d.n.angel

I've been rereading and rewatching DNAngel, and on thing that I can't remember is where the two of the came from. Did they just appear one day, or did someone create them?

Comment: Dark and Krad are two halves of the Hikari work "The Black Wings."

Answer (score 1):

Dark and Krad are two halves of the Hikari work ["The Black Wings."](http://dnangel.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Wings_(Artwork)).

As for how and why they come to manifest, it was never elaborated upon in the manga or anime.

[image: The Black Wings]

Answer (score 1):

In the anime they are the two halves of Blackwings without much information to it. In the manga: actually Blackwings was its own artwork and Hikari was about to give it life when Niwa attempted to take it, interrupting the ritual. This had a side effect that the magic ended up on both men, but not for giving, but for taking life (both Dark and Krad are cursed to stop both lineages: Dark by making it difficult for the person to show or be overflown by affection and love, which can make being in a relationship difficult; Krad makes near impossible needing or caring for others and actively used method to destroy the cursed person). All this is in the Argentine Qualia arc of the manga.

Answer (score 0):

The Hikari family created an artwork and they became the two halves of it. They are the soul of it. So they were probably created by the Hikari with the artwork. It is in the anime.